# Getting Count of Cached Data Without Hitting Server

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

Let's say I have the following React component:

```
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'

const MovieListContainer = () => (
  <Query query={QUERY}>
    {
      ({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return (<p>Loading...</p>)
        if (error && !data) return (<p>Error...</p>)
        return <MovieList movies={ data.movies }
      }
    }
  </Query>
)
```

Essentially, this is used to get the list of movies from the GraphQL cache (hitting the server if necessary) to display. I want to minimize the time that a user will see the "Loading" screen, so I might do something like this when initializing my app:

```
import { MOVIE_QUERY } from './queries'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://example.com:3000/graphql'
})
// Query the movies immediately, and refresh every 30 seconds
client.query({ query: MOVIE_QUERY })
client.watchQuery({query: MOVIE_QUERY }, pollInterval: 30000)

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Layout />
  </ApolloProvider>
)
```

This works well. The problem is, now let's say that I want to make another component that displays the number of movies in the list....

```
const MovieTab = ({ count }) => {
  <Tab>
    <span>Movies</span>
    <Badge>{ count }</Badge>
  </Tab>
}
```

How do I create a container to hook `MovieTab` up to the Apollo cache to get the list of movies without causing a database hit (displaying a '??' in the badge if necessary)? Some things I've tried:

- Wrap it in a `Query`, where the query is just something like `movies { id }`. I've posted this as an answer, but I'm still not crazy about it.
- Wrap it in a `Query`, where the query is MOVIE_QUERY. Seems to go against the idea of using GraphQL to get only the data needed.
- Wrap it in ApolloConsumer to get access to the client then call `readQuery` to get the list of movies. This guarantees that I won't hit the database, but won't work until the cache is actually filled with data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
const QUERY = gql`
movies { id }
`

const MovieTabContainer = () => (
  <Query query={ QUERY } fetchPolicy='cache-only'>
    ({ data }) => {
      const count = data.movies ? data.movies.length : '??'
      return (
        <MovieTab count={ count } />
      )
    }
  </Query>
)
```

By specifying that the fetch policy is cache-only, we will immediately pass `data` (which will be an empty object). We can take this as a sign that we don't know the count quite yet. Once the cache is filled by executing the full movie query, the MovieTab component will be rerendered to include the actual length.

Answer (score 1):

If the query's already being fetched elsewhere, I think using `MOVIE_QUERY` with a `cache-only` is a fine and simple workaround. Assuming that you're not accessing a public API or at least can exert some control over how the API is designed, the cleanest solution here may actually be a server-side one.

Rather than structuring your schema like this:

```
type Query {
  movies: [Movies!]!
}
```

you could instead mix in some metadata, minimally something like this:

```
type Query {
  movies: QueryResult
}

type QueryResult {
  total: Int
  items: [QueryItem!]!
}

union QueryItem = Movie | Actor | Director
```

That would let you query your cache for the total directly.